# Monitoring multiple instance App Service Plan

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-app-service-plans

I scale out an App Service Plan to 2 instances. So how to monitor each instance individually. **Metrics** board has no option for this, only show average of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's a bit old thread but wanted to provide an update if you are still looking for a response on it.

I believe your requirement is currently not a supported feature so I would recommend to raise a feature request in [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps) Azure feedback forum / UserVoice. In general, Azure feature team would check feasibility of the feature request, prioritize against existing feature backlog, add in roadmap as appropriate and would announce and/or update the related Azure document once a feature request is addressed.

Answer (score 0):

We can see how many instances are created and destroyed in a certain time, for each App Service, through App Insights with a kusto query:

```
requests
 
| project cloud_RoleName, cloud_RoleInstance

| order by cloud_RoleName desc
 
| summarize Count=dcount(cloud_RoleInstance) by cloud_RoleName, cloud_RoleInstance
```

Instances per App Service:

[image: Instances per App Service]